# How to call a function in my_helper from routes in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-helpers

I have a function named `enable_disable(param1,param2)` in `my_helper.php`.

How can I call this `enable_disable(param1,param2)` from `routes.php` in codeigniter?

Please share your great ideas if anyone have the key.

Comment: why would you want that in routes.php?

Comment: @LogicBlower dear I have a function which is common in all the controller(s).Actually I want to put that in helper and called it from routes.php by passing two param i.e. table_name and status.

Answer (score 0):

Write that code (`enable_disable($p1, $p2)` function) in pre_system [hook](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html). It is being loaded before router. If you want quick and dirty way, you can put it into `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` file at the end.